# Web API 404 File or Directory not Found for "root" routes

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7, asp.net-web-api

I am developing a RESTful web api service. It's web api v.1, not v.2. Also I am developing on Visual Studio 2010 SP1. I have installed the MVC 4 for VS2010 SP1.

Please understand and keep in mind that Upgrading to newer versions of VS or Web Api 2 is not an option.

I have the following problem **after a Windows Update ocurred**.

When I try to use my RESTful api this way....

http://url.com/documents/ (get all the documents) I get the following error...

The resource cannot be found.

**Description:** HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Here is the stack trace.

```
[HttpException]: File does not exist.   at System.Web.StaticFileHandler.GetFileInfo(String virtualPathWithPathInfo, String physicalPath, HttpResponse response)   at System.Web.StaticFileHandler.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpContext context, String overrideVirtualPath)   at System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)   at system.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

If I specify the action name directly, it works. For example...

http://url.com/documents/get (gets all the documents) or

http://url.com/documents/7 (gets document id=7.

It only fails when you call it by its default name. I have already read similar situations here and I have tried to follow their solutions but they are not working for me properly.

Now, I know this **is not** a "web api routing" issue because I actually get the .net default exception page html markup (I am using Postman to test my webservice). When I force  a "routing issue", then I get a JSON error description, which means that the Controller actually got created in the pipeline and returned a response.

Also, I have a custom file (SecurityHandler) that inherits from DelegatingHandler. This file gets executed almost first in the pipeline with each call to the api. Even before the actual Controller. Well, this file is never called when I get the error, which confirms to me that the "webserver" (either VS Development Server or IIS 7) is the one throwing the exception.

I have exhausted every single solution that I have found here. Change my web.config to multiple handlers configurations, re-installed MVC 4 for VS2010, created an entire new project... all these efforts have shown no results whatsoever.

Like I said, this was working perfectly fine until my pc restarted from a Windows Update BUT... why does it fail in the server as well? I did deploy my api to the server after the error started to occur.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not in Web API (and has nothing to do with it's version or Visual Studio 2010), it's the static file handler trying to serve and failing.

Alternatives:
0. Do you have a documents folder in your site? Get rid of it.
1. Remove the static file handler for directory browsing and re-add it.
2. Use RAMMFAR (less recommended)

Comment: Yishai, seems like it was a "routing order issue". Cannot understand how it was working before (i think it was yourself who helped me to get it straight in the first place) but later it broke. I switched the routing mapper from the most specific to the less one and it worked again. Thanks